# Consume REST web service with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, rest

I have a web service that displays a data in the JSON format at a certain URL, my question is how can I store this data in a variable using jQuery. I've tried this so far :

```js
$.ajax( {
type:'Get',
url:'http://localhost:8080/demo/x',
success:function(data) {
 alert(data);
}

});
```

But it doesn't alert anything when I got to the page where I have put this script.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: maybe try adding a handler for failure and see if that catches anything?

Comment: Share java code for the exposed service as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shorthand .get() with your get request. Add a failure handler:

```js
$.get("http://localhost:8080/demo/x", function(data) {
  alert("Retrieved data:" + data);
}).fail(function() {
  alert("An error has occurred");
});
```

Comment: If you get an error, try inserting http://localhost:8080/demo/x into the URL bar of your browser, and see what response you get.

Comment: I tried localhost:8080/demo/x into the URL bar and I get the right data in the JSON format. I used your script and got "An error has occured".

Comment: Is your page on the same domain as the rest service that you are calling?

Comment: Is your page also on localhost, same as the rest service? If not, then you've encountered a common cross-domain script restriction issue - have a look at this link:  http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET', 
   url: 'http://localhost:8080/demo/x',
   data: {
      format: 'json'
   },
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data) {
      alert('Data: ' + data);   
   },
   error: function() {
      alert('Error');
   }   
});
```