# javascript - How can I give a variable the value from a webservice?

Tags: javascript

I'm no javascript guru. I have tryed to find an answer, but no luck.

How can I give a variable the value from a webservice?

my service http://localhost:5000/Token is a basic rest service that returns a simple string.

I can see that my webservice is invoked, but I don't get any alert

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {   

    function getToken() {
         var data = "hello";
         $.get("http://localhost:5000/Token", function(response) {
             data = response;
         }).error(function() {
             alert("Sorry could not proceed");
         });

         return data;
     }

    var token = getToken();

    alert(token);
    </script>
```

Comment: The syntax is not valid. You aren't going to see anything.

Comment: The ajax call is asynchronous. You need to consume the value in the `function(response) { }` method. You immediately return a value of `hello` and throw away the real return values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469234/consume-rest-web-service-with-jquery